# Python - List of List of strings

Tags: python, list, data-structures

So, basically I have a Queue (List of List of strings). Now, suppose I want to append 'okay' to the list at index 1, why is it getting appended for all the lists inside Queue? How do I append a value to a specific list only inside Queue?

```
Queue = []
temp = []
Queue.append(temp) # 12 - 8
Queue.append(temp)
Queue.append(temp)
Queue[1].append('okay')
print(Queue)
```

```
[['okay'], ['okay'], ['okay']]
```

Comment: You are appending multiple copies of exactly the same list `temp` to `Queue`. You need to append *new* lists instead.

Comment: They're all the same list, so ... they're the same. append(temp.copy()) or in some cases deepcopy()

Comment: Thank you I understood!

Answer (score 1):

**Your `Queue` is a list of the exact same list**

`Queue.append(temp)` does not create a new list and add it to `Queue`. Therefore when you change one element of `Queue`, you are actually changing them all.

`Queue.append([])` should be used to populate the queue with *separate*, empty lists.

Answer (score 1):

Because the three items in Queue are not three different empty lists: they're all `temp`. Thus `temp`, `Queue[0]`, `Queue[1]` and `Queue[2]` are all the same object and modifying one of them has the result of modifying them all.

Try the following code instead:

```
Queue = []
Queue.append([])
Queue.append([])
Queue.append([])
Queue[1].append('okay')
print(Queue)
```

Answer (score 0):

replace temp = [] with list()

```
Queue = [ ]
Queue.append(list()) # 12 - 8
Queue.append(list())
Queue.append(list())
Queue[1].append('okay')
print(Queue)
output: [[], ['okay'], []]
```